# PocketBeagle enable com port on usb0

Tags: debian, systemd, usb, embedded, beagleboneblack

I'm attempting to configure a pocketbeagle running bone-debian9.9. Kernel version is 4.14.108-ti-r113. The board has a Micro USB port with the following functions: rndis, acm, ecm, and mass_storage. the USB interface (usb0) lets me obtain a shell two ways - by ssh and through the COM  port.

I would like the COM port on usb0 to not be a shell. I want to be able to plug in the device, open the COM port, and receive a stream of bytes. I can send/receive arbitrary bytes via the UART peripherals by wiring one to a usb-to-serial converter and opening a COM port. Is it possible to get this from the USB COM port as well. How can I accomplish this?

What I've tried/considered so far:

1) I tried getting rid of the log in terminal, thinking that serial-getty@service was the problem. After masking the service I could not open a COM port.

2) I'm not sure that I need to write another driver - I would think the acm driver would be enough.

3) Modifying /etc/systemd/logind.conf so that NAutoVT=0 and ReserveVT=1 didn't help either.

Another thing that may be related:
I needed uart0, which was also was a shell. I got rid of the shell by masking serial-getty@ttyO0.service and serial-getty@ttyS0.service. My application configured a terminal on /dev/ttyO0 using termios.h and then it worked. I'm wondering if masking serial-getty@service was the correct thing to do and I should register some kind of callback to configure a terminal when the USB device is connected. If that's the case then I could use the approach outlined here: https://serverfault.com/questions/766506/automount-usb-drives-with-systemd

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that systemctl mask serial-getty@GS0.service was correct. To use the serial port i then had to open /dev/ttyGS0 using open() and configure it using termios